# What does translation-table-for-input in function zap-to-char

Tags: variables

I am reading the [8.1.2 The Body of zap-to-char of Elisp Introduction](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/eintr.html#zap_002dto_002dchar-body)

The body of `zap-to-char`

```
 (if (char-table-p translation-table-for-input)
     (setq char (or (aref translation-table-for-input char) char)))
 (kill-region (point) (progn
                        (search-forward (char-to-string char) nil nil arg)
                        (point)))
```

What does the variable `translation-table-for-input` do here?

Its default value is 'nil` by my emacs setting.

Comment: Have you asked Emacs?  `C-h v translation-table-for-input` gives you a summary, and `C-h S translation-table-for-input` takes you to the info node `C-h i g (elisp)Translation of Characters` which tells you more about translation tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does variable `translation-table-for-input` do here?

It potentially translates `char` to some other char.

```
(setq char (or (aref translation-table-for-input char) char))
```

is saying: "if char has a mapping in `translation-table-for-input` then use that; otherwise keep its original value".

That then affects what the subsequent search is searching *for*.